# Enabling Nesting for Xen-in-Xen via Libvirt xml

Tags: centos, xen, libvirt

I'm trying to get nested Xen-In-Xen via libvirt.  Can someone confirm that adding hap and nestedhvm to the features element in the domU xml config is what is required to get nesting working?  Am I missing any other steps?

```
<features>
  <acpi/>
  <apic/>
  <pae/>
  <hap/>
  <nestedhvm/>
</features>
```

once adding these I do not see 'vmx' listed as a flag in /proc/cpuinfo, but I do see the 'hypervisor' flag... is this the confirmation I should expect, or should I see the vmx flag within a nested hypervisor?

This has been my reference material: http://wiki.xenproject.org/wiki/Nested_Virtualization_in_Xen

Thanks All!

Comment: Are you using CentOS Xen? **xm** or **xl** stack?

Comment: I'm using libvirt on CentOS Xen.  If I understand correctly it uses libxl.  http://wiki.xen.org/wiki/Choice_of_Toolstacks

Comment: As I understand libvirt is an own toolstack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading through the link you provided I would say you forgot the CPU-mask. Try that and perhaps then the *vmx* will appear.

Comment: That bit of the doc says masking is only if I intend on installing "VMware-ESX, VMware-Workstation, (or) Win8-hyperv".  I'm doing Xen-in-Xen, can you confirm that the masking is still required?  Also, the '..xxxxxx....'  is that what I actually enter for mask?

Comment: @DayFox I assume that every virtualization solution needs the same masking. And yes, you need to input those x.